# How to make ssh client in android

Tags: android, android-intent, ssh

I want to make an android phone application for monitoring the router and its configuration using an ssh client like `connectbot`. Monitoring application is complete, but setup is not yet complete. How can I connect connectbot with my android application that I created in eclipse? Should I use the Intent to connectbot?

thanks .....

Answer (score 5):

Connectbot is open source, so you could just reuse their code, if the license fits your needs: http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/

Answer (score 0):

you can try termius
i think it is the best SSH client for Mac,IOS and Android